# What is the value of performance in an application, in dollar form?

Tags: performance, memory, big-o

This isn't just a question for me, but for anyone wondering how important it is to make things more daft punk like (faster, better, and stronger ;) ). I don't know enough about this topic, even though I try my best to make things work the best. But I am curious as to what a company like google might pay for a better sorting algorithm, or a better search algorithm.

My main reasoning for asking this question is because I have developed, and am working on a method, for a search algorithm, that works in O(8) every time. That's right, not O(8n), but O(8). I'm not sure about the memory, but it is extremely quick. Quick enough to be instant. It would stop the need for splitting up your data across servers.

Anyways back to the question. How much, in money (so people can ACTUALLY understand the value), do/ would companies spend on things like speed, memory usage, and file size?

Comment: Performance of an application matters - but only if the developer's time spent on improving the performance is less than the aggregate mount of performance felt by users of it, e.g. if I spent 1 hour improving performance it's only worth it if it saves my users 1 hour or more collectively over the lifespan of my program.

Comment: Er, so constant time? How can you search in constant time?

Comment: Interesting question, but your question as phrased contains virtually no content (only you bragging about something that is physically impossible). The only relevant sentence is the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Distributed Computing Economics](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70001) written by Jim Gray in 2003 is a good start. See this quote:

> From this we conclude that one dollar equates to
>
> - = 1 $
> - ≈ 1 GB sent over the WAN
> - ≈ 10 Tops (tera cpu operations)
> - ≈ 8 hours of cpu time
> - ≈ 1 GB disk space
> - ≈ 10 M database accesses
> - ≈ 10 TB of disk bandwidth
> - ≈ 10 TB of LAN bandwidth

Obviously the values have changed since then, but this is very concrete data pointing to the fact that performance counts.

A more recent post related to this subject on High Scalability blog: [At Scale Even Little Wins Pay Off Big - Google And Facebook Examples](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/2/11/at-scale-even-little-wins-pay-off-big-google-and-facebook-ex.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's buried in this hard to read blog post, but there's some very telling tidbits about how real users respond to slow operations in http://blogs.adobe.com/jd/2008/08/factors_affecting_realworld_ad.html

I found the macromedia study he mentions a few years ago, but sadly can't find it now. It described shockingly high falloff for adoption as download times increased.

Takeaway: Users are incredibly impatient. Be fast, or lose.